# Expected Compatibility Issues with upcoming TLS/SSL Cipher Suite update on Azure WebApps?

Tags: ssl, azure-web-app-service

A little while ago we received an email from the Azure Team regarding an upcoming TLS/SSL cipher suit update, kicking in after July 18th with the following instruction:

> You can check whether the clients that access your web apps will still function correctly by testing them against https://testsslclient.trafficmanager.net/. Your client is compatible if you receive a 200 HTTP status—the page will display a “SSL client test complete!” message.

After testing our standard clients it looks like IE7 and IE8 fail the test on XP SP3 (Chrome still works).

Does anybody else have results of what clients are expected to fail? (It would have been nice if the Azure Team would have provided a list of expected incompatibilities).

Also: the test page uses an SHA2 certificate. We are still using SHA1 on some sites, due to be updated eventually. Does anybody know if the update will have any impact on SHA1 certificates?

[Related link](https://richardjgreen.net/azure-web-app-ssl-cipher-suite-changes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have repeated our tests today and IE7 and IE8 on XPSP3 now pass the client test at https://testsslclient.trafficmanager.net.

We assume the implementation of the TLS/SSL cipher suit has been updated to allow for this now...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, XPSP3 IE 7/8 will fail because they don't support any of the ciphers that will be on the updated list. I don't think we have a list of clients that will / will not work, because the list is quite large ... you have to worry about embedded devices like PoS terminals etc, and not just browsers.

SHA-1 certificates will still be supported in Azure WebApps, although some browsers like Chrome will complain about obsolete cryptography etc.